# Can I anyone tell me what these circle icons are?

Tags: samsung, app-icons

[image]

Can anyone tell me what these circle icons are

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the grey circles with lower half circle, it is the [Upday](https://www.upday.com/en/) news app.